# The variable address in Objective C language

Tags: objective-c

I know that if the computer is 64 bit, then a int variable occupy 4 bytes. I try to test this by the following code.

```
int c = 16;
int f = 11;
NSLog(@"&c = %p &f = %p", &c,&f);
```

and the output is:

```
&c = 0x7fff570c8a4c &f = 0x7fff570c8a48
```

The discrepancy is 4, does this mean that the variable occupy 4 bytes? Where is the pointer of int and the int variable store in computer, stack or heap? Do pointer and variable store in different places?

I want to understand why the discrepancy of 2 the address of int is 4.

Comment: Why do you think `int` is 64-bit? Try `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: Many 64-bit compilers keep an *int* at 4 bytes.  Using the processor caches effectively is important.  Check your compiler's [data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).

Comment: Stack allocated variables don't have to be consecutively laid out in memory, so talking about the distance between a pair of local variables makes little to no sense (not to mention that pointer arithmetic is undefined between pointers that are not on the same array, or one element past the end). Nevertheless, your logic that ints must be 8 bytes in a 64-bit system is flawed; they can be 4 bytes, or (theoretically) even as small as 2 bytes (the minimum imposed by the standard)

Comment: Am I the only one who never saw NSLog function on C ? but only on Objective-C ?

Comment: To go very low level, all we mean when talking about x bit computers is that the width of the processor's data bus is x bits. That does not have anything to do with data type sizes in C.

Comment: Updated as above, I used the objective c language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that if the computer is 64 bit, then a int variable occupy 64/8=8 bytes.

This is not true in general. For example, 64-bit Windows systems use 32-bit `int`s.

Regardless, the locations of variables on the stack are somewhat arbitrary, and cannot be relied upon to determine anything about those variables' size. (It is true *in this case* that these variables occupy four bytes, but the same will not be true in all circumstances.) If you need to determine the "bit-ness" of a system within a program, consider taking the size of a pointer, e.g.

```
sizeof(void *)
```

This will always return 4 for systems which use 32-bit addresses, and 8 for systems which use 64-bit addresses.

Comment: Can you tell me why the discrepancy of 2 the address of int is 4?

Comment: @Jay `NSLog(@"%d", sizeof(int))`.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it does mean the variable occupies 4 bytes.  And the pointers you asked about are stored on the stack for the call to NSLog().

Comment: What's with the down votes?  My answer is direct and clear.  And correct.

Comment: I haven't downvoted you, but your answer makes assertions that aren't necessarily true. For example, it is possible for `int` to occupy 2 bytes. It is also possible for arguments to be in places other than the stack (typically, registers).

Comment: This answer lacks detail, makes wrong assumptions, and fails to point out a number of issues in the OP's code. Pointer arithmetic is undefined unless both pointers belong on the same array, or one element past the end. So technically the code has UB. Proving that an `int` is 4 bytes with this method is flawed. `sizeof` is usually a much more reasonable choice.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis, While it is possible for an int to occupy 2 bytes, the OP's output shows that it does not in his case.  And alternative locations for arguments are certainly possibly, but the stack is the most common.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves, 1) It lacks detail, because it is simply direct.  He did not ask for a comprehensive understanding, as is often the case.  2)  It makes assumptions, but they are not shown to be wrong or even unlikely.  3)  It "fails" to point out a number of issues in the OP's code, because he didn't ask for that.

Comment: Since the original post, there has been an edit, saying the OP wants "to understand why ..."

Comment: @donjuedo (1) The compiler is free to choose non-consecutive memory locations for automatic variables, so the correct way to check for size isn't to calculate from the addresses of nearby variables (unless it's an array, which is guaranteed to be contiguous). (2) Especially if the question is about Objective-C (judging from `NSLog`), the calling convention is likely to be that of the System V AMD64 ABI, which places the first six integer and pointer arguments to registers.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis, You are right -- the correct way is not what he did, and I would never use that technique myself.  `sizeof()` is fine.